# Mobile nav items not toggling to close

Tags: css, mobile, responsive, nav

Probably one of the worst things I could be doing but I've taken a snippet of code from codepen that I really liked for my new bootstrap 5 site that animates a burger menu usgin CSS. It opens the nav items fine on mobile view, but then I can't get it to close. Not sure what I have to do to get it to close the items? I assume it's because I'm not toggling a close option but not sure how to write it properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```css
/*Nav overrides*/
.navbar{background-color:transparent!important;}
.navbar a{color:white;}
.navbar a:hover{color:#c08cf1;}
.navbar-brand{color:#FFF; font-size:1.6rem;}
.navbar-collapse{flex-grow:0;}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(192,140,241, 0.5)' stroke-width='4' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border:none;
  display:contents;
} 

/*Animated burger menu STARTS*/
.ham {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: transform 400ms;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.hamRotate.active {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.hamRotate180.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.line {
  fill:none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke:#c08cf1;
  stroke-width:5.5;
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
.ham1 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 139;
}
.ham1 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 180;
}
.ham1.active .top {
  stroke-dashoffset: -98px;
}
.ham1.active .bottom {
  stroke-dashoffset: -138px;
}
/*Animated burger menu ENDS*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Nav -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MHARRISON<span style="color:#c08cf1;">DESIGN</span></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
            <path
                  class="line top"
                  d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" />
            <path
                  class="line middle"
                  d="m 30,50 h 40" />
            <path
                  class="line bottom"
                  d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
 <!-- Nav ENDS -->
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```